# Is there a way to specify the reduce() accumulator in Python?

Tags: python, haskell, reduce

I've been learning a lot of Haskell lately, and wanted to try out some of the neat tricks it has in Python. From what I can understand, Python's reduce automatically sets the iterative variable and the accumulator in the function passed to the first two values of the list given in reduce. In Haskell, when I use its equivalent, fold, I can specify what I want the accumulator to be. Is there a way I can do this with Python's reduce?

Comment: *reduce(function, sequence[, initial])* "If initial is present, it is placed before the items
of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
sequence is empty." Is this what you want?

Answer (score 12):

Quoting [reduce docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce), an interface is:

```
reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])
```

> If the optional *initializer* is present, it is placed before the items
>   of the iterable in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
>   iterable is empty. If initializer is not given and iterable contains
>   only one item, the first item is returned.

So, an (academic) example for using initializer may be:

```
seq = ['s1', 's22', 's333']
len_sum_count = reduce(lambda accumulator, s: accumulator + len(s), seq, 0)
assert len_sum_count == 9
```